# What is correct (English grammar): Combination of singular/plural but is it was OR were?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Could someone please tell me what is correct:

> Shareholders’ ownership of ABC-Company **was** 1,000,000 shares, which equals 1.5% of equity.

or

> Shareholders’ ownership of ABC-Company **were** 1,000,000 shares, which equals 1.5% of equity.

Reason for my question: I understand that *was* is for singular, while *were* is for plural. What I am asking is whether the verb should agree with *ownership* (singular) or with *shares* (plural).

Comment: The head of the subject NP is the singular "ownership" so it follows that the verb should be singular "is".

Comment: It is as @BillJ says. Q: What was (or were) 1,000,000 shares?  A: Shareholder’s [sic] **ownership was**.”

Comment: It's nonsensical for ***shareholder*** to be singular here, so the text is effectively invalid. It should be plural* ***Shareholders'** ownership was...* Where the possessive apostrophe is ***written*** after the plural noun, but the actual possessive ***s*** is neither written nor enunciated, so this kind of orthography error isn't uncommon. That's got nothing to do with the fact that the "head noun" of the verb subject is ***ownership*** - which is singular, as has been pointed out.

Comment: There are also another couple of issues with the sentence. "equals **to**" and "**an** equity" aren't right either. Try "which equals 1.5% of equity".

Comment: It should be "shareholder ownership" or "the shareholders' ownership"

Comment: Just a note. Stocks and shares are different things.  Saying "also known as" in the question is incorrect.

Comment: Did you write those? Because they are  not in standard financial lingo, fyi. I don't see the point of correcting poorly written text.

Answer (score 0):

It is always and only with their subjects that verbs must agree, so the correct form here is *was*. The situation is completely parallel to

> John’s height was six feet.

We certainly wouldn’t say, *”John’s height **were** six feet.”

In your sentence, “1,000,000 shares” quantifies shareholders’ ownership in exactly the same way that “six feet” quantifies John’s height.